# how to print message 'included' along with limit_1 value, when limit_1 is selected with condition

Tags: mysql, query

```
select  max(Contract_Num) as contract_num,
        max(Lic_Plate_Num) as lic_plate_num,
        max(cast(Revision_Eff_Date as date)) as rev_eff_date, 
        max(contract_name) as cn_name,
        max(CASE WHEN product_code = 'CSL' THEN Limit_1 END) as value_1 ,
        max(CASE WHEN c.product_code in ('PIP','FPB') THEN Limit_1 END) as value_2,
        max(CASE WHEN product_code = 'MEDPM' THEN Limit_1 END) as value_3,
        max(CASE WHEN c.product_code in ( 'UMUIM','UMISG','UMCSL') THEN Limit_1 END) as value_4,
        max(CASE WHEN c.product_code in ( 'UNCSL','UNDSG') THEN Limit_1 END) as value_5         
from [dba].[Contract] as a
left join [dba].[CDAA_Vehicle] as b on a.Contract_ID=b.Contract_ID
left join [dba].[Contract_Product] as c on c.Contract_ID=a.Contract_ID
left join dba.Contract_Name as d on c.Contract_ID = d.Contract_ID
left join dba.Contract_Article ca on c.Contract_ID = ca.Contract_ID
where ca.Status!='D'
```

and the output is

```
contract_num  lic_plate_num  rev_eff_date  cn_name value_1 value_2 value_3 value_4 value_5 
1231           V24B32        12-09-2022    test     null    null    100    200      367
```

This is my query and output, here I'm selecting limit_1 value based on product and the limit_1 value may or may not be null. but here I want to print one message 'Included' for individual product limit_1, when the limit_1 value is not null.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL ? `[dba].[Contract]` isn't valid in MySQL

Comment: `COALESCE(limit_1, "Included")`